# PHPMailer in a custom php function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I made a custom class function for setting up the basic information needed by PHPMailer (so I don't need to input it in everytime). Here is the exact code of the function.

```
<?php

class PHPMailer {

    public static function send() {// I will just add here the addAddress
        require_once 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "validusername";
        $mail->Password = "validpassword";
        $mail->setFrom('validusername', 'Valid Username');
        $mail->addAddress('googol8080@gmail.com', 'Googol');

        $mail->Subject = "Subject";
        $mail->Body    = "<a href=\"www.google.com\">www.google.com</a>";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            return "Error sending message" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            return "Message sent!";
        }
    }
}
```

So far it is working on my localhost, but I have questions:

- Is this a good practice?
- Is the code okay?
- Is there any drawback/s about this?
- If there is need to optimize here for performance, what do I need to do to make it happen?

I am really new in PHP and PHPMailer any small answers might help me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Code seems fine, but a better way could be to call `variables`, so you dont have to configure it everytime you want to call the class.

```
class phpmailer {
    public function sendMail($email, $message, $subject)
    {
        require_once('../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        require_once('../phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
        require_once('../phpmailer/class.pop3.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "email_password";
        $mail->setFrom('email_Sent_from@gmail.com', 'Alias');
        $mail->addReplyTo("email_to@gmail.com", "Alias");
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($message);
        $mail->send();
    }
}
```

then you can call it like:

```
$email_send = new phpmailer();
$email_send->sendMail($user_email,$message,$subject);
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the purpose of those 3 `require_once` ? Thanks.

Comment: the first is for the php mailer class, the second and third are for smtp and pop3 if you want to use them

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for that, btw, when I tried to send a simple email (localhost) and it takes upto 2 seconds to send. Is that okay? I mean I am using a localhost and it takes upto 2 seconds, what will happen if I use that in production (shared hosting) ? Might take upto 2 - 5 secods?

Comment: thats normal dude :)

Comment: I know this is like AGES old, but I just tried the above, and got this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method phpmailer::isSMTP()`
Any thoughts?

Comment: you cant call a method statically that is not defined

Comment: In this case, what's the advantage of building a class, instead of using a simple function?