# How to add PHPmailer in if else statement and send email through it with a button click?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, phpmailer

I have an HTML table and in one of its cells, there is a button to Accept food orders. That data is then checked by another PHP page if it's ok or not and then the data is updated accordingly. Below is the code I used for the HTML table button:

```
.
.
//codes
.
.

<td>
<center>".$totalamount."</center></td>
   <td><center>".$payment_mode."</center></td>
   <td><center>".$datetime."</center></td>                          
   <td><center><a class='btn btn-primary' href='orderstatus.php?orderid=".$orderid."&orderstatus=Accept'>Accept</center></a>
</td>";?>
</tr>
```

As you can see the last `<td>` cell consists of the button which links to another PHP page **orderstatus.php**. Below is the code for this page:

```
.
.
//codes
.
.
while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($userinfocon))
{
    $username=$data2['username'];
    $useremail=$data2['email'];
}

if($orderstatus=="Accept")
{

//codes

}
if($orderstatus=="InKitchen")
{

//codes

}
if($orderstatus=="Ready")

//codes
```

Now I want that whenever the status is a particular value or whenever a button is clicked it should send an email to the user using PHPMailer() about their order status.

I tried to do it by adding the PHP mailing code after every if-else statement but that ends up creating a loop that keeps on sending me emails.

I am a beginner in PHP so I am not able to understand what should be done.

Comment: Create a function like `function send_mail($recipient,$message)` for sending mail. You can make phpmailer settings in the function and use the function wherever you want.

Comment: I think this will help you. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114809/phpmailer-in-a-custom-php-function)

Comment: Ok so should i create that function in a different php file? Or in the same file and then call it?

Comment: If create that function in a different php file you should include to current file

Comment: Ok I got you. I am doing as you suggested

Comment: Can you **please** show me the format for doing this? I am confused at where to start and what to add where!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114809/phpmailer-in-a-custom-php-function  flow this link sent by @ŞahinErsever , you can understand the concept